# Using Artisan::call() to pass non-option arguments

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

In the shell I can create a database migration (for example) like so:

```
./artisan migrate:make --table="mytable" mymigration
```

Using Artisan::call() I can't work out how to pass a non-argument parameter ("mymigration" in this example). I have tried many variants of the code below:

```
Artisan::call('db:migrate', ['--table' => 'mytable', 'mymigration'])
```

Anyone got any ideas? I have been using shell_exec('./artisan ...') in the meantime but I'm not happy with the approach.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

#### Before Laravel 5

```
Artisan::call('db:migrate', ['' => 'mymigration', '--table' => 'mytable'])
```

#### Laravel 5 onwards

```
Artisan::call('db:migrate', ['argument-name-as-defined-in-signature-property-of-command' => 'mymigration', '--table' => 'mytable'])
```

See other answers for more details.

Comment: You are right - I meant migrate:make - but the question was about artisan commands in general. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Throws an error in Laravel 5.4. I would recommend Ikos answer.

Comment: Also this won't work with multiple arguments...  Associative arrays must have unique keys....

Comment: I doesn't work with multiple arguments and from version 5.4

Answer (score 30):

In laravel 5.1 , you set options with/without values when calling an Artisan command from your PHP code.

```
Artisan::call('your:commandname', ['--optionwithvalue' => 'youroptionvalue', '--optionwithoutvalue' => true]);
```

in this case, inside your artisan command;

```
$this->option('optionwithvalue'); //returns 'youroptionvalue'

$this->option('optionwithoutvalue'); //returns true
```

Comment: I think this answer is solved another problem - How to pass non-value options to artisan command? In my case this was a solution because I needed to pass '--force' option to 'migrate' command.

Comment: This one does it ! Thank you @iko!

Comment: From 5.4 this is the only way to do it

Answer (score 16):

The solution is different if you're using Laravel 5.1 or newer.  Now what you need to do is you need to know the name that was given to the argument in the command's signature.  You can find the name of the argument from your command shell by using `php artisan help` followed by the command name.

I think you meant to ask about "make:migration".  So, for example `php artisan help make:migration` shows you that it accepts a parameter called "name".  So you can call it like this: `Artisan::call('make:migration', ['name' => 'foo' ])`.

Comment: This is the solution that worked perfectly for myself. Using Laravel 5.3

Comment: This should be THE solution

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is pretty old but this came up first on my Google search so I'll add this here. @orrd's answer is correct but I'll also add that for cases that use an array of arguments where you use the asterisk `*` you need to supply the argument(s) as an array.

For example if you have a command that uses array arguments with a signature like:

```
protected $signature = 'command:do-something {arg_name*}';
```

In these cases you need to supply the arguments in an array when you call it.

```
$this->call('command:do-something', ['arg_name' => ['value']]);
$this->call('command:do-something', ['arg_name' => ['value', 'another-value']]);
```

Answer (score 2):

In you command you add getArguments():

```
/**
 * Get the console command arguments.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getArguments()
{
    return array(
        array('fdmprinterpath', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Basic slice config path'),
        array('configpath', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'User slice config path'),
        array('gcodepath', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Path for the generated gcode'),
        array('tempstlpath', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Path for the model that will be sliced'),
        array('uid', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'User id'),
    );
}
```

You can use the arguments:

```
$fdmprinterpath = $this->argument('fdmprinterpath');
$configpath     = $this->argument('configpath');
$gcodepath      = $this->argument('gcodepath');
$tempstlpath    = $this->argument('tempstlpath');
$uid            = $this->argument('uid');
```

call you command with parameters:

```
Artisan::call('command:slice-model', ['fdmprinterpath' => $fdmprinterpath, 'configpath' => $configpath, 'gcodepath' => $gcodepath, 'tempstlpath' => $tempstlpath]);
```

For more info refer to this [article](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/your-one-stop-guide-to-laravel-commands--net-30349).

Answer (score 1):

In other alternative way you can execute only specific migration in Laravel

```
Artisan::call('migrate --path=database/migrations/path_to_your_migration_with_php_extention');
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Artisan::call('db:migrate', ['--table' => 'mytable', 'mymigration'=>true])
```